# Minus the time problem?

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Sever 2005

From the below Query Am getting total worked time means Outtime  - Intime, Suppose when I minus the Next day time means showing wrong time

Query

```
Select ID, Normal_Intime, Normal_Outtime, Date, Intime, outtime, CONVERT(char(8), CASE WHEN InTime < Outtime THEN CASE WHEN OutTime > Normal_Outtime THEN CAST(Normal_Outtime AS datetime) ELSE CAST(Outtime AS datetime) END - CASE WHEN InTime < Normal_Intime THEN CAST(Normal_Intime AS datetime) ELSE CAST(Intime AS datetime) END ELSE CASE WHEN InTime < Normal_Intime THEN CAST(Normal_Intime AS datetime) ELSE CAST(Intime AS datetime) END - CASE WHEN OutTime > Normal_Outtime THEN CAST(Normal_Outtime AS datetime) ELSE CAST(Outtime AS datetime) END END, 8) AS workedtime from table1
```

Output

```
ID Normal_Intime, Normal_Outtime, Date Intime, Outtime, Worktime

01  10:00:00 19:00:00 01/09/2009 08:20:56 15:40:15  05:40:15
01  18:00:00 05:00:00 02/09/2009 15:00:59 08:20:16  13:00:00
```

First One is Correct, 
Second Worktime should give 11:00:00 Hours only because Intime 18:00:00 and Outtime is 05:00:00 (next day 05:00:00 am), Now It is working as 18:00:00 - 05:00:00 giving as 13:00:00. It should give only 11:00:00

How to minus the next day time.

Need Query Help

Comment: Still storing the dates in varchar fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case out time is less than in time then add 24 to it before minus

Comment: I think this will be faster than using datediff function

Comment: How to add 24. Can You tell me

Comment: datepart(hour,[Normal_outtime])+24

Answer (score 0):

Don't use substraction, use the `datediff` function instead.